# selectable RecyclerView performance issues

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I am currently trying to achieve an app to edit weekly timeframes.
Like mechanical timers for sockets, but in my case for every weekday.

[image]

The granularity is in the first place secondary (i guess it will be 15 or 30min).

My approach was a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` and an `ArrayAdapter` with Items for every Cell.

To select more cells you can longpress a cell and drag over others. To achieve this I used the Listeners of the following Library [DragSelectRecyclerView](https://github.com/MFlisar/DragSelectRecyclerView).

It works pretty well and you can select the items quite good but especially on the emulator or older phones its very slow and laggy. In the debug logcat you can see also that the Choreographer has to skip many frames at rendering the View and on selection of multiple cells.

[image]

Is there an better approach to achieve such an behavior. Or is there any big mistake in the code which is very slow and crappy?

**EDIT:**

after changing  `notifyItemChanged(pos);` to `notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, pos);` its way less laggy but still not performing as well as it should.

I also removed everything that was responsible for autoscrolling (which was a feature of the library i mentioned above) to make the code simpler.

Here the source of my `Fragment`

```
    public class TestFragment extends Fragment
    {
        @BindView(R.id.gridView_hours) GridView gridView_hours;
        @BindView(R.id.weekdays_container) LinearLayout weekdays_container;

        private String[] hours = new String[]{"00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00"};
        private String[] hoursShort = new String[]{"00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"};

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
            {
                RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(getActivity());
                initAdapter(recyclerView);

                GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 48, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);

                weekdays_container.addView(recyclerView);

            }
            gridView_hours.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.hour_view, hoursShort));

    //        GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 48, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    //        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);

            return view;
        }

        private void initAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView)
        {
            TestAutoDataAdapter adapter = new TestAutoDataAdapter(getActivity(), 48);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            DragSelectionProcessor dragSelectionProcessor = new DragSelectionProcessor(new DragSelectionProcessor.ISelectionHandler() {
                @Override
                public HashSet<Integer> getSelection() {
                    return adapter.getSelection();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isSelected(int index) {
                    return adapter.getSelection().contains(index);
                }

                @Override
                public void updateSelection(int start, int end, boolean isSelected, boolean calledFromOnStart) {
                    adapter.selectRange(start, end, isSelected);
                }
            });

            DragSelectTouchListener dragSelectTouchListener = new DragSelectTouchListener()
                    .withSelectListener(dragSelectionProcessor);
            recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(dragSelectTouchListener);

            adapter.setClickListener(new TestAutoDataAdapter.ItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position)
                {
                    adapter.toggleSelection(position);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(View view, int position)
                {
                    dragSelectTouchListener.startDragSelection(position);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

and the `RecyclerView.Adapter`

```
    public class TestAutoDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAutoDataAdapter.ViewHolder>
    {

        private int dataSize;
        private Context context;
        private ItemClickListener clickListener;

        private HashSet<Integer> selected;

        public TestAutoDataAdapter(Context context, int size)
        {
            this.context = context;
            dataSize = size;
            selected = new HashSet<>();
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.test_cell, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            holder.tvText.setText("");
            if (selected.contains(position))
                holder.tvText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            else
                holder.tvText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            return dataSize;
        }

        // ----------------------
        // Selection
        // ----------------------

        public void toggleSelection(int pos)
        {
            if (selected.contains(pos))
                selected.remove(pos);
            else
                selected.add(pos);
            notifyItemChanged(pos);
        }

        public void select(int pos, boolean selected)
        {
            if (selected)
                this.selected.add(pos);
            else
                this.selected.remove(pos);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, pos);
        }

        public void selectRange(int start, int end, boolean selected)
        {
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
            {
                if (selected)
                    this.selected.add(i);
                else
                    this.selected.remove(i);
            }
            notifyItemRangeChanged(start, end - start + 1);
        }

        public void deselectAll()
        {
            // this is not beautiful...
            selected.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void selectAll()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
                selected.add(i);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public int getCountSelected()
        {
            return selected.size();
        }

        public HashSet<Integer> getSelection()
        {
            return selected;
        }

        // ----------------------
        // Click Listener
        // ----------------------

        public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener)
        {
            clickListener = itemClickListener;
        }

        public interface ItemClickListener
        {
            void onItemClick(View view, int position);
            boolean onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
        }

        // ----------------------
        // ViewHolder
        // ----------------------

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener
        {
            public TextView tvText;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView)
            {
                super(itemView);
                tvText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvText);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
                itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if (clickListener != null)
                    clickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view)
            {
                if (clickListener != null)
                    return clickListener.onItemLongClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

the SelectTouchListener

```
    public class DragSelectTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener
    {
        private static final String TAG = "DSTL";

        private boolean mIsActive;
        private int mStart, mEnd;
        private int mLastStart, mLastEnd;

        private OnDragSelectListener mSelectListener;

        public DragSelectTouchListener()
        {
            reset();
        }

        /**
         * sets the listener
         * <p>
         *
         * @param selectListener the listener that will be notified when items are (un)selected
         */
        public DragSelectTouchListener withSelectListener(OnDragSelectListener selectListener)
        {
            this.mSelectListener = selectListener;
            return this;
        }

        // -----------------------
        // Main functions
        // -----------------------

        /**
         * start the drag selection
         * <p>
         *
         * @param position the index of the first selected item
         */
        public void startDragSelection(int position)
        {
            setIsActive(true);
            mStart = position;
            mEnd = position;
            mLastStart = position;
            mLastEnd = position;
            if (mSelectListener != null && mSelectListener instanceof OnAdvancedDragSelectListener)
                ((OnAdvancedDragSelectListener)mSelectListener).onSelectionStarted(position);
        }

        // -----------------------
        // Functions
        // -----------------------

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (!mIsActive || rv.getAdapter().getItemCount() == 0)
                return false;

            int action = e.getAction();
            switch (action)
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    reset();
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (!mIsActive)
                return;

            int action = e.getAction();
            switch (action)
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    updateSelectedRange(rv, e);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    reset();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void updateSelectedRange(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e)
        {
            updateSelectedRange(rv, e.getX(), e.getY());
        }

        private void updateSelectedRange(RecyclerView rv, float x, float y)
        {
            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(x, y);
            if (child != null)
            {
                int position = rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && mEnd != position)
                {
                    mEnd = position;
                    notifySelectRangeChange();
                }
            }
        }

        private void notifySelectRangeChange()
        {
            if (mSelectListener == null)
                return;
            if (mStart == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION || mEnd == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                return;

            int newStart, newEnd;
            newStart = Math.min(mStart, mEnd);
            newEnd = Math.max(mStart, mEnd);
            if (mLastStart == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION || mLastEnd == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
            {
                if (newEnd - newStart == 1)
                    mSelectListener.onSelectChange(newStart, newStart, true);
                else
                    mSelectListener.onSelectChange(newStart, newEnd, true);
            }
            else
            {
                if (newStart > mLastStart)
                    mSelectListener.onSelectChange(mLastStart, newStart - 1, false);
                else if (newStart < mLastStart)
                    mSelectListener.onSelectChange(newStart, mLastStart - 1, true);

                if (newEnd > mLastEnd)
                    mSelectListener.onSelectChange(mLastEnd + 1, newEnd, true);
                else if (newEnd < mLastEnd)
                    mSelectListener.onSelectChange(newEnd + 1, mLastEnd, false);
            }

            mLastStart = newStart;
            mLastEnd = newEnd;
        }

        private void reset()
        {
            setIsActive(false);
            if (mSelectListener != null && mSelectListener instanceof OnAdvancedDragSelectListener)
                ((OnAdvancedDragSelectListener)mSelectListener).onSelectionFinished(mEnd);
            mStart = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
            mEnd = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
            mLastStart = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
            mLastEnd = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept)
        {
            // ignore
        }

        public void setIsActive(boolean isActive)
        {
            this.mIsActive = isActive;
        }

        // -----------------------
        // Interfaces and simple default implementations
        // -----------------------

        public interface OnAdvancedDragSelectListener extends OnDragSelectListener
        {
            /**
             * @param start      the item on which the drag selection was started at
             */
            void onSelectionStarted(int start);

            /**
             * @param end      the item on which the drag selection was finished at
             */
            void onSelectionFinished(int end);
        }

        public interface OnDragSelectListener
        {
            /**
             * @param start      the newly (un)selected range start
             * @param end        the newly (un)selected range end
             * @param isSelected true, it range got selected, false if not
             */
            void onSelectChange(int start, int end, boolean isSelected);
        }
    }
```

and the Implementation of the needed Interface

```
    public class DragSelectionProcessor implements DragSelectTouchListener.OnAdvancedDragSelectListener {

        private ISelectionHandler mSelectionHandler;
        private HashSet<Integer> mOriginalSelection;
        private boolean mFirstWasSelected;
        private boolean mCheckSelectionState = false;

        public DragSelectionProcessor(ISelectionHandler selectionHandler)
        {
            mSelectionHandler = selectionHandler;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSelectionStarted(int start)
        {
            mOriginalSelection = new HashSet<>();
            Set<Integer> selected = mSelectionHandler.getSelection();
            if (selected != null)
                mOriginalSelection.addAll(selected);
            mFirstWasSelected = mOriginalSelection.contains(start);

            mSelectionHandler.updateSelection(start, start, !mFirstWasSelected, true);

        }

        @Override
        public void onSelectionFinished(int end)
        {
            mOriginalSelection = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSelectChange(int start, int end, boolean isSelected)
        {
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
                checkedUpdateSelection(i, i, isSelected ? !mFirstWasSelected :  mOriginalSelection.contains(i));
        }

        private void checkedUpdateSelection(int start, int end, boolean newSelectionState)
        {
            if (mCheckSelectionState)
            {
                for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
                {
                    if (mSelectionHandler.isSelected(i) != newSelectionState)
                        mSelectionHandler.updateSelection(i, i, newSelectionState, false);
                }
            }
            else
                mSelectionHandler.updateSelection(start, end, newSelectionState, false);
        }

        public interface ISelectionHandler
        {
            Set<Integer> getSelection();

            boolean isSelected(int index);

            void updateSelection(int start, int end, boolean isSelected, boolean calledFromOnStart);
        }
    }
```

Comment: your screenshots is broken.

Comment: both images are still working for me. even after clearing cache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use `notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, pos);`, `notifyDataSetChanged()` etc. on each selection process.

Why won't you like this;

1.Took your recyclerview references in its adapter like this:

```
 private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
 public TestAutoDataAdapter(Context context, int size, RecyclerView pRecyclerView){
        this.mRecyclerView = pRecyclerView;
        ..
```

2.Set background color of the selected viewholder like this:

```
       public void select(int pos, boolean selected){
          // Get selected view holder from recyclerview
          ViewHolder holder = recyclerview..findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos);

            if (selected)
                this.selected.add(pos);
            else
                this.selected.remove(pos);
            //notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, pos);
            holder.tvText.setBackgroundColor(selected ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);

        }
```

Change your whole selection process like this way and let me know the result.

Comment: works like charm :)
I knew it ... such an easy solution for my problem -.-
one note to improve your suggestion ... I would rather use `onAttachedToRecyclerView` for passing over the reference to the `RecyclerView`